# how to connect to external wifi camera on android using OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, camera, ip-camera

I am making researches on image processing on how to detect objects using android smart phones.

I am trying to use an external WiFi camera instead of using the android's own camera to perform the object detection. Is it possible to do this using opencv? Are there any limitations like it can only use its own android device camera for the detection, etc?

If it is possible to connect to an external WiFi camera, where can I find  examples on how to establish the connection on android and make it detect some objects on that WiFi camera?

I have already trained an XML file to detect a particular object and I would only like to establish a connection to the external WiFi camera and perform the detection on the WiFi camera.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Watch out with asking questions like "May I know ...", few will answer "Yes you may" (which might be correct but would not help you), but it always better to keep the question crisp. No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), that also means leaving out hings like "Thank you", "please", and advanced announcements of appreciation. It is not impolite to leave that out but it is wasting readers time when you put it in.

Answer (score 1):

What's an interesting idea! I tried to imagine it and I figured out this as a possible solution:

- You can implement a camera viewer application that has motion detection feature and makes RTSP streaming possible.
- Thereafter you can watch the image of your remote camera on your Android smartphone by using a media player supporting RTSP streaming (e.g. VLC).

In this [collection of camera code examples](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_14-online-manual-for-the-ozeki-camera-sdk-onvif.html) you can find guides related to all above described.

Please let me know if it was helpful. I'm really interested in your solution!